# Laravel 5.7 - Ajax call e Session::get()

Tags: ajax, laravel, session

Tem dias que estou batendo cabeça para ler dados de uma `Session` através de um `ajax` `call`.

Em uma aplicação sem `Framework` faço isso normalmente utilizando o `PHPSESSION`, porém no `Laravel 5.7` não consigo de forma nenhuma.

Meu ambiente: Servidor Ubuntu + PHP 7.2 + Laravel 5.7 utilizando file como  session driver

Meu `ajax` `call`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/nota/consulta?id_cliente='+id_cliente+'&item='+item,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

Meu controller:

```
public function getNota(Request $request) 
{
    if ($request->session()->has('nota')) 
    {
        $nota = $request->session()->get('nota');
        return response()->json($nota);
    }   
    return response()->json(array('msg'=>'erro'));
}
```

A sessão existe pois printo ela na `View`, mas o result do `ajax` não trás os dados. Acredito que tenha algo no `Laravel` que esteja me impedindo de ler dados da Session quando a requisição é feita pelo Ajax, pois se eu abrir o link no navegador os dados aparecem.

Comment: Qual é a sua rota?

Comment: Oi Virgilio, estou utilizando routes\web.php com a seguinte rota: 
 Route::get('/nota/consulta', 'TrocaController@getNota');

Comment: console.log retorna o que?

Answer (score -1):

Passe os dados pra rota usando post, não se passa parâmetros em url de ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/nota/consulta,
    dataType: 'json',
    method: 'post',
    data: {
      id_cliente: id_cliente,
      item : item
    }
    success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```